# extract url from text by matcher using regex expression

Tags: java, android, regex, extract

I am pretty new to regex expression ,i have a code source of an page and i want to extract  URL from this code , am using matcher to find the url as a group ,am trying this regex expression Pattern.compile("\"https:.*?\"")for that but i still failed .
the  URL look like this :

"https://scontent-mad1-1.cdntest.com/vp/**8e2f9af8362ea131062778fccbfda09e/5AEB6394/t51.2885-19**/s320x320/**12918047_263707850629206_1737689122**_a.jpg"

the part with strong font is variable, and the rest of url is stable part

Any help pls !

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use the .indexOf method if you know how the strings starts and ends?

String.Substring(string.indexOf("http"),string.indexOf(".jpg"))

Maybe you should add the .jpg at the end again.

Comment: am using matcher/pattern ! if i don't know the end of the url , how should be the regex expression ?